# Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch for coherent sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

The main theme of my question is how to compute the holomorphic Euler characteristic of a *coherent* sheaf via something like Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch

Let $X$ be smooth, projective, Calabi-Yau manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$.  Let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ with one-dimensional support *not necessarily pure*.  In other words, I would like E to be supported on a curve and points, in general.

I would like to compute the holomorphic Euler characteristic $\chi(X, E)$ of $E$.  My partial attempt is as follows, but I'm not positive it's legitimate:

First I assume that $E$ is pure of dimension one, with smooth, connected support.  In this case, there exists a curve $\iota :C \hookrightarrow X$ with a vector bundle $F$ on $C$ such that $E=\iota_{*}F$, and

$$\text{ch}_{k}(E) =0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{for all}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, k<n-1$$

Naively applying Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch, I find

$$\chi(X, E) = \int_{X} \text{ch}(E) \text{td}(X) = \int_{X} \text{ch}_{n}(E),$$

where the final equality requires the Calabi-Yau condition.  My two questions:

**1. Can I apply HRR in this manner even though $E$ is not a vector bundle?**

and

**2. What if $E$ is not pure?  If $E$ is also supported on points, I'd like to still argue that**

$$ \chi(X, E)=\int_{X} \text{ch}_{n}(E).$$

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Huybrechts comments in the affirmative in his book "Complex Geometry." There is small discussion on page 237, and he references papers by O'Brian, Toledo, and Tong.

Comment: This should drop right out from Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch applied to the case where the morphism is just the structure map $X \to Spec(\mathbb C)$.